# Grails: Error running forked test-app: No such property: Ant for class: _Events

Tags: unit-testing, grails

I'm using Grails 2.4.4, and when I run `test-app -unit -clean` I get the following error.  Within the grails shell, I can run still run individual unit tests

```
Testing started at 12:05 PM ...
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Dgrails.home=/Users/terskine/.sdkman/candidates/grails/2.4.4 -Dtools.jar=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar -Dgroovy.starter.conf=/Users/terskine/.sdkman/candidates/grails/2.4.4/conf/groovy-starter.conf -Xmx768M -Xms768M -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:PermSize=256m -Dbase.dir=/Users/terskine/git/myphotoid-api -Dgrails.build.listeners=org.jetbrains.groovy.grails.rt.GrailsIdeaTestListener -Dgrails.project.fork.test.debugArgs -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Users/terskine/.sdkman/candidates/grails/2.4.4/lib/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all/jars/groovy-all-2.3.7.jar:/Users/terskine/.sdkman/candidates/grails/2.4.4/dist/grails-bootstrap-2.4.4.jar org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter --classpath "/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/Grails/lib/grails-rt.jar" --main org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner --conf /Users/terskine/.sdkman/candidates/grails/2.4.4/conf/groovy-starter.conf "test-app -unit -clean --stacktrace -plain-output"
|Loading Grails 2.4.4
|Configuring classpath
.
|Environment set to test
.......................................................
|Running without daemon...
objc[82887]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java (0x10171a4c0) and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib (0x10178a4e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
| Error Error running forked test-app: No such property: Ant for class: _Events (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Ant for class: _Events
    at _Events$_run_closure2.doCall(_Events.groovy:17)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
| Error Error running forked test-app: No such property: Ant for class: _Events
Error |
Forked Grails VM exited with error

Process finished with exit code 1
```

---

**Update: In response to comment**

I have a custom Events script in my application.

```
eventCreateWarStart = { warName, stagingDir ->
    Ant.delete(dir: "${stagingDir}/build")
    Ant.delete(dir: "${stagingDir}/node_modules")
    Ant.delete(dir: "${stagingDir}/src")
    Ant.delete(dir: "${stagingDir}/test")
    Ant.delete(file: "${stagingDir}/aurelia.protractor.js")
    Ant.delete(file: "${stagingDir}/gulpfile.js")
    Ant.delete(file: "${stagingDir}/jsconfig.json")
    Ant.delete(file: "${stagingDir}/karma.conf.js")
    Ant.delete(file: "${stagingDir}/package.json")
    Ant.delete(file: "${stagingDir}/protractor.conf.js")
}
```

Comment: Do you have a custom Events script in your project?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown , yes. I added the contents of our `_Events.groovy` file to the question above. Do I need to import `Ant`?

Answer (score 0):

I found this GitHub issue which helped

> This is a problem with how the asset pipeline wants to be initialized. It does things with compiled classes in `_Events.groovy` when things haven't necessarily been compiled yet. The only way that I know of to make it go away is to not have a clean target directory and [to do] that, you first need to `grails package` before you do a `grails run-app` (or `test-app` or `war`) so that the asset pipeline classes are compiled first and available to `_Events.groovy`.

So, I ran the following and it worked:

```
grails clean
grails package
grails test-app
```

Afterward, I was able to run `grails clean ; grails test-app`, but I still get the same error when I run `grails teat-app -clean`, but I can live with that for now.  If anyone can explain this better, I would appreciate it.